# Typescript Failed To Compile Even After Modifying Namespace

Tags: typescript, express

I'm trying to expand the `User` type inside `express.js` by adding an `express.d.ts` declaration file to my project. The declaration file removes the squiggly error lines inside VS Code but Typescript wont compile. I'm getting errors such as `TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User'` when I try to compile even though intellisense is recognizing the declarations.

**express.d.ts**

```js
import { Channel, User as DbUser } from '../entities'

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            channel?: Channel
        }

        //User already exists on Request and is of type {}
        interface User extends DbUser {

        }
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES2017",
        "pretty": true,
        "strict": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noImplicitThis": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": [ "ESNext" ]
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        // ...brevity
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "ts-loader": "^5.4.5",
        "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
        "typescript": "^3.7.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        // ...brevity
        "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
        "@types/express-serve-static-core": "^4.17.2",
    }
}
```

**compilation error**
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/middleware/authorize.ts(8,34): error TS2339: Property 'session' does not exist on type 'Request'.
src/middleware/authorize.ts(10,35): error TS2339: Property 'badges' does not exist on type 'User'.
src/middleware/authorize.ts(25,34): error TS2339: Property 'session' does not exist on type 'Request'.
src/middleware/authorize.ts(27,35): error TS2339: Property 'badges' does not exist on type 'User'.
src/middleware/authorize.ts(42,34): error TS2339: Property 'session' does not exist on type 'Request'.
src/middleware/authorize.ts(44,35): error TS2339: Property 'badges' does not exist on type 'User'.

Comment: I'm looking at `@types/express` and `@types/express-serve-static-core` in DefinitelyTyped and can't see any property or type called `User` in any of them. Could you show us your compilation error output?

Comment: I added some compilation errors. Please excuse some of the extra errors that don't match up with the declaration I posted, as I wanted a minimal example

Comment: so I did some digging and user actually is defined by `@types/passport`

Comment: Are you sure you're extending the existing `Request` interface and not overriding its definition? I know it might be possible with declaration merging, but maybe that's not exactly happening here.

Comment: No, how would I go about testing if I'm overwriting the interface? Intellisense gives me all of the usual properties on the req object but I recorgnize that intellisense is a different system than the compiler

Answer (score -1):

‍ **You can try** this code below to declare your own express interface:

```js
import { Channel, User as DbUser } from '../entities'

declare module 'express' {
  interface Request {
    channel?: Channel
  }

  interface User extends DbUser {
  }
}
```

> I've been try that code above and it's working fine.

I hope it can help you .

Comment: It does not work, using this code causes the red squiggly error lines to appear in VSCode. If it helps, I can click `go to type definition` on the user object it brings me to  the definition inside `@types/passport`

Comment: I've been try that code above and it's `true` it's working fine. Make sure to import the file, because it's not a global declaration.

Comment: What you have there isn't working for me, could it be because you don't have passport installed?

Comment: It still working, you can see at my example code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/199z5hqjmVx_Ofl20M2UDlkhnPqNk4mVF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your link doesn't allow me to see what's inside the files. I can see that your project doesn't use a declaration file.

Comment: It's a zip file, you've to download it and extract in your computer and run it.

Comment: Your'e project doesn't demonstrate the solution at all, there is no declaration file augmenting the express `Request` type.

Comment: I don't add express `Request` type becuase I think your problem is in `interface User extends DbUser`. But if you want, you can add your own and it's still working fine. **I think you don't try my code, because it's realy working fine**, Mybe you should to read your question, where's error, it's in `User`, you're not talking about express `Request`

Comment: I think it is not difficult work, if you just copy your Request interface and place it in the `declare` that I have given and only because of that problem are you giving a 'downvote'? It's really funny where you want to be helped but you always hope that other people work for you and if not, it's like you will shoot their heads.